# Problema com String em C, exclusão de termo na string, através de comparação de strings

Tags: c, string

Elaborei um código que excluía o termo semelhante nas duas strings, porém ele não imprime o resultado do texto tirando o segundo termo, somente retira o primeiro termo da primeira string.

"Crie um programa que receba uma frase e um termo. Caso o
termo esteja presente na frase, remova-o e imprima a frase
modificada, caso contrário, exiba “Termo não encontrado na
frase”.Considere o tamanho de string máximo igual a 200."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char texto[200];
    char word[10];
    int l1, ind, tam, j = 0, i, c = 0, r;

    scanf("%s", texto);
    gets(texto);
    scanf("%s", word);
    tam = strlen(texto);

    for (i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
      r = strcmp(texto, word);
      j = j + 1;
    }

    if ((texto != '\0') && (word != '\0')) {
        for (i = 0; i < l1; i++) {
          ind = (strlen(texto)-1) / j;
          j = j + 1;
        }
        printf("%s\n", texto);

    } else
    {
        printf("Termo não encontrado na frase.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque é que tem `scanf("%s",texto);` e `gets(texto);` ?  basta ter o `gets(texto);`
Com o scanf a ler o texto, vai só ler até onde existir espaço, ou seja, lê apenas a primeira palavra do texto. Use o gets

Comment: @IanMoone - o recomendado é usar fgets, não gets, que é muito fácil de dar problemas, porque pode sobrescrever a memória fora da área de leitura.

Comment: editei o código para colocar espaços, facilita muito a leitura...no "mundo real" ninguém usa o tipo de código C que aparece aqui no SO, tudo grudado e sem espaços...outro problema deste código (e da maioria absoluta dos códigos C que aparece aqui) é a absoluta ausência de comentários explicando o código...quem não consegue explicar **no código** o que está acontecendo, então de maneira geral não sabe o que está acontecendo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções `strstr()` e `memmove()`, ambas da biblioteca padrão `string.h`.

A função `strstr()` pode ser usada para fazer a busca do termo dentro da frase e a função `memmove()` para remover o termo, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char * posicao = NULL;
    char frase[200];
    char termo[200];

    printf("Digite a frase: ");
    scanf( "%[^\n]%*c", frase );

    printf("Digite o termo: ");
    scanf( "%[^\n]%*c", termo );

    /* Procura e recupera posicao do termo na frase */
    posicao = strstr( frase, termo );

    /* verifica se o termo foi encontrado */
    if( posicao == NULL )
    {
        printf("Termo não encontrado na frase.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Remove o termo da frase */
    memmove( posicao, posicao + strlen(termo), strlen(posicao) - strlen(termo) + 1 );

    /* Exibe frase modificada */
    printf("Frase modificada: %s\n", frase );

    return 0;
}
```

Testando:

```
Digite a frase: O rato roeu a roupa do rei de roma.
Digite o termo: roupa
Frase modificada: O rato roeu a  do rei de roma.
```

Comment: não sabia sobre algumas funções predefinidas na biblioteca string, logo tentei realizar a força.

Answer (score 1):

Tem vários problemas no seu código e coisas que não está usando, mas antes de os indicar, começo por apresentar uma solução seguindo mais ou menos a sua lógica:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char texto[200], word[10];
    //ambas as leituras com scanf
    scanf("%199[^\n]", texto);
    scanf("%9s", word);

    int i, presente = 0, tam = strlen(word);
    for(i = 0; texto[i] != '\0'; i++) { //percorre cada letra do texto
        if (memcmp(&texto[i], word, tam) == 0){ //testa se na letra em que vai existe a palavra
            presente = 1; 
            //loop para remover a palavra do texto
            for (; texto[i] != '\0'; i++){ 
                texto[i] = texto[i + tam];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (presente) {
        printf("%s\n",texto);
    } else {
        printf("Termo não encontrado na frase.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/Q1kq9k)

Para testar a existência da palavra a partir de uma determinada letra utilizei a função [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/), que compara blocos de memória e permite indicar quantos bytes devem ser comparados.

Agora voltando à sua solução. As leituras não estão boas:

```
scanf("%s",texto);
gets(texto);
scanf("%s",word);
```

Leu duas vezes o `texto` e está a juntar `scanf` com `gets` que é convidar o desastre. Evite fazer isso ao máximo, de preferência não usando de todo o `gets` que foi *deprecated* (marcado como obsoleto) em C++.

Tem várias variáveis que não está usando, como o `r`:

```
for(i=0;i<l1;i++){
    r=strcmp(texto,word);
    j=j+1;
}
```

Neste `for` você compara o texto com a palavra e guarda o resultado em `r`, mas não o usa. Também o resultado vai ser sempre igual pois você compara o texto todo e não apenas a partir de uma letra especifica. Para alem disso o fim do loop é feito com `i < l1`, mas `l1` não foi sequer inicializado.

Mais à frente usou também `tam=strlen(texto);` mas não tem qualquer uso no resto do programa.

Comment: "%s9" --> "%9s" etc

Comment: @zentrunix obrigado :), foi desatenção mesmo

Comment: este também: "%[^\n]199"

Comment: @zentrunix Peço desculpa, não faço um post no site com isto pois sei que não é motivo de criar um post, contudo gostaria que me esclarecessem uma dúvida. Para que serve o [^\n] no scanf? qual a diferença entre `scanf("%s[^\n]");`e `scanf("%s");`?

Comment: @IanMoone Isso é para ler até ao final da linha, pois o `scanf("%s")` lê apenas uma palavra. Não precisa de fazer um post, pode perguntar aqui pois fui eu que coloquei isso na minha resposta

Comment: Ah ok, já entendi. Muito obrigado pela explicação.